# How to build the generated server project using swagger editor

Tags: java, maven-3, swagger, swagger-editor

I get below error when build the generated server project in swagger editor using maven 3.0.5 version. I used maven 3.3.9 also. still failing with the same error. java version is 1.8.0_40. what is the reason for this build failure? 
You can easily reproduce this by generating server project for uber API in swagger editor and building it using maven.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/Attributes
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Attributes
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
```

Comment: You're talking about the jaxrs generated server?

Comment: yes.it is...............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could built the server by commenting `jetty-maven-plugin` in pom file. Seems like it tries to start a jetty server and deploy the generated server jar file.